# How to read strings separated by ',."/()" " \n

Tags: c, string, get, scanf

I'm trying to read strings separated by `',."/()" " \n`, until `EOF`. I only need to read words and numbers -- that will, later, be added to a tree.

An example of input text:

> Luis Vaz de Camoes Os Lusiadas
>
> Canto Primeiro
>
> As armas e os baroes assinalados, Que da ocidental praia Lusitana, Por
>   mares nunca de antes navegados, Passaram ainda alem da Taprobana, Em
>   perigos e guerras esforcados, Mais do que prometia a forca humana, E
>   entre gente remota edificaram Novo Reino, que tanto sublimaram;
>
> E tambem as memorias gloriosas Daqueles Reis, que foram dilatando A
>   Fe, o Imperio, e as terras viciosas De africa e de asia andaram
>   devastando; E aqueles, que por obras valerosas Se vao da lei da morte
>   libertando; Cantando espalharei por toda parte, Se a tanto me ajudar o
>   engenho e arte.
>
> Cessem do sabio Grego e do Troiano As navegacoes grandes que fizeram;
>   Cale-se de Alexandro e de Trajano A fama das vitorias que tiveram; Que
>   eu canto o peito ilustre Lusitano, A quem Neptuno e Marte obedeceram:
>   Cesse tudo o que a Musa antigua canta, Que outro valor mais alto se
>   alevanta.
>
> E vos, Tagides minhas, pois criado Tendes em mim um novo engenho
>   ardente, Se sempre em verso humilde celebrado Foi de mim vosso rio
>   alegremente, Dai-me agora um som alto e sublimado, Um estilo
>   grandiloquo e corrente, Porque de vossas aguas, Febo ordene Que nao
>   tenham inveja as de Hipoerene.
>
> Dai-me uma furia grande e sonorosa, E nao de agreste avena ou frauta
>   ruda, Mas de tuba canora e belicosa, Que o peito acende e a cor ao
>   gesto muda; Dai-me igual canto aos feitos da famosa Gente vossa, que a
>   Marte tanto ajuda; Que se espalhe e se cante no universo, Se tao
>   sublime preco cabe em verso.

I need to read the words and numbers to save them in a tree.

Comment: -1 for no effort shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) should be a big help here, this is an example using most of the separators you identified:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="As armas e (os) baroes assinalados, Que da ocidental praia Lusitana. Por mares nunca de antes";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str,"',.\"()\n ");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, "',.\"()\n ");
  }
  return 0;
}
```